# Problem with main menu background color

Tags: routes

I'm almost new with Drupal . so far i could do almost every thing i wanted by customizing the Bartik theme .
one problem i have right now is to change the main menu color "when selected". It has the same color as the site background and the only way to change it , is to change the site back ground color too , but i don't want that. I opened style.css file and there i could change any color of the menus except when they are selected. I think what i want to change is [#main-menu-links a:active] , but when i added this line : [background-color:#ff1221;] in it, nothing happens and it keeps having the back ground color of site when selected.
what do you think the problem is ?